# Can you restore stored procedures from a EF 6.0 .edmx

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, restore

I finished up a MVC application using EF 6.0 in August there are several stored procedures that were lost in September when the developer database was rolled back. This was after the application's UAT but before the project was deployed.  The database stored procedures were not backed up, I have all of the stored procedure results in the .edmx, is there any way I can get the stored procedures out of the .edmx, or am I going to be asking for a tape backup from over a month ago?

Comment: All the EDMX contains is the definition of the stored procedure input/output. The code of your stored procedure existed only in the database. You're going to need to go to backup. The source code for stored procedures (and triggers, views, etc) should all be in source control just like any other source code.

Comment: Thanks!  I was afraid that might be the case. You've got it dead to rights on the stored procedures belonging in a database project.  I started doing that in September, but never had bandwidth to go back to this project. . .